# Is there a way to set as initial camera in a 3D plot that the upper left corner is (0,0,0)? Plotly

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python

I'm trying to set as initial camera of a 3D volume plot where the upper left corner is the origin `(x, y, z = 0)`. I've read the [documentation](https://plotly.com/python/3d-camera-controls/) about the camera controls but cannot figure out how can I accomplish this.

The initial view I want it's something like this:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried it and this one work on me

If you want the front upper left corner as (0,0,0)

```
camera = dict(
    eye=dict(x=0, y=-0.5, z=-2.5)
)
fig.update_layout(scene_camera=camera, title=name)
fig.show()
```

what I understand from this eye is basically the position of the eye(or you) look at eyepoint(0,0,0) which is I believe the center of the 3D graph (not the coordinate)

And if you need to change the axes direction to the opposite, you can try to put it on negative on the eye position, and if it is zero you can put negative small number (in this example I used -0.5, but you can use -0.01 too)

Comment: It works, the only inconvenient is that I invert the z-axis, so the front upper left corner as `(0,0,zmax)`, do you have any suggestions? I try doing the opposite `eye=dict(x=-0.01, y=0.5, z=2.5)` and the result is `(xmax,0,0)`

Comment: so you want (0,0,0) is on the back upper left? `eye=dict(x=0, y=-0.01, z=2.5)` should do the trick